# ISO 20022 XML message digital Signing using SignXML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, signing, digital

I am at sample code to digitally sign & verify ISO 20022 XML document.  Any code samples would help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please review and edit your question with a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I've been working with another OP on similar case.  See following link and my link to an old case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60318515/how-to-create-digitally-signed-xml-message-using-standard-iso20022-in-net-c-s#comment106729238_60318515