# Hash values do not match

Tags: soap, hash, sha1

I get a response: Hash values do not match.

I have the following code:

```
public string SignSoapMessageVersion(string soapRequest,X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
    RSA privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();

    // Load the SOAP request into an XML document
    XmlDocument soapEnvelope = new XmlDocument();
    soapEnvelope.PreserveWhitespace = true; // Preserve whitespace
    soapEnvelope.LoadXml(soapRequest);
    KeyInfo keyInfo = AddKeyInfoPFX(certificate,soapEnvelope);
    SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(soapEnvelope);
    signedXml.SigningKey = privateKey;
    signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;
    signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = 
    "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1";
    signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = 
    SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
    AddReferencesToSignedXml(signedXml);
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    XmlElement signatureElement = signedXml.GetXml();
    InsertSignatureIntoEnvelope(soapEnvelope, signatureElement);
    // Convert the modified XML document back to string
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    soapEnvelope.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter);
    string signedSoapRequest = stringWriter.ToString();

    return signedSoapRequest; 

}
```

After creating signedSoapRequest i send it over HTTP. Because the Hash does not match i expect a change of the xml, but i can't find that. I also checked my CanonicalizationMethod, but it is correct. I have looked for hours, but i can't see the problem.

The XML is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:ns="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" wsu:Id="header-id">
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd#base64binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="BST-75A5B475BDAC322DB1281E2F7F6D508A3FA01F35">{binarysecuritytoken}</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
<ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2828">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>xfMJtd2LNORdDHd8FrWvZ3v6bKk=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#timestamp-id">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>pWpXBZk3+AoXZD9vnjQR8bVHIik=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2830">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>Zne8qDKNG8EoX7jEb/GiGUuwrn4=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2831">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>rhTgRqv1al0xXnIIaUiWIlYmJSk=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2832">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>W0zDCg76HEpF5kk4uM8QrMGewJw=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
<ds:Reference URI="#id-2829">
<ds:Transforms>
<ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</ds:Transforms>
<ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<ds:DigestValue>NMDB73UNT5oviV5V8OuG/tqItSA=</ds:DigestValue>
</ds:Reference>
</ds:SignedInfo>
<ds:SignatureValue>{securitytoken}</ds:SignatureValue>
<ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyId-75A5B475BDAC322DB1281E2F7F6D508A3FA01F35">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="STRId-75A5B475BDAC322DB1281E2F7F6D508A3FA01F35">
<wsse:Reference xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" URI="#BST-75A5B475BDAC322DB1281E2F7F6D508A3FA01F35" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
<wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="timestamp-id">
<wsu:Created>2024-03-25T19:23:31.976Z</wsu:Created>
<wsu:Expires>2024-03-25T19:28:31.976Z</wsu:Expires>
</wsu:Timestamp>
</wsse:Security>
<wsa:Action xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2831"> http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/afleverservice/1.2/AfleverService/afleverenRequest </wsa:Action>
<wsa:ReplyTo xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2832">
<wsa:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:Address>
</wsa:ReplyTo>
<wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2830">uuid:0a528087-4b2e-4d89-ba5d-a0168b344f04</wsa:MessageID>
<wsa:To xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2829">https://FQDNBedrijf/wus/2.0/afleverservice/1.2</wsa:To>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-2828">
<ns:aanleverRequest xmlns:ns="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/">
<ns:berichtsoort>Jaarrekening</ns:berichtsoort>
<ns:aanleverkenmerk>12345678_2023-12-31</ns:aanleverkenmerk>
<ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
<ns:nummer>12345678</ns:nummer>
<ns:type>KvK</ns:type>
</ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
<ns:rolBelanghebbende>Intermediair</ns:rolBelanghebbende>
<ns:berichtInhoud>
<ns:mimeType>application/xml</ns:mimeType>
<ns:bestandsnaam>12345678_2023-12-31.xbrl</ns:bestandsnaam>
<ns:inhoud>{XBRL}</ns:inhoud>
</ns:berichtInhoud>
</ns:aanleverRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SignedXML:

```
       public class SignedXmlWithId : 
       SignedXml
              {
                public 
               SignedXmlWithId(XmlDocument 
                 xml) : base(xml)
                {
                }
    
                public 
                SignedXmlWithId(XmlElement 
                xmlElement)
                    : base(xmlElement)
                {
                }
    
                public override XmlElement 
                GetIdElement(XmlDocument 
                doc, string id)
                {
                    // check to see if it's a standard ID reference
                    XmlElement idElem = base.GetIdElement(doc, id);
    
                    if (idElem == null)
                    {
                        XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
                        nsManager.AddNamespace("wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
    
                        idElem = doc.SelectSingleNode("//*[@wsu:Id=\"" + id + "\"]", nsManager) as XmlElement;
                    }
    
                    return idElem;
                }
            }

        private KeyInfo AddKeyInfoPFX(X509Certificate2 certificate, XmlDocument soapEnvelope)
        {
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            // Create the KeyInfo object
            // Calculate the Subject Key Identifier
            // Convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string
            string subjectKeyIdentifierString = CalculateSubjectKeyIdentifierBase64(certificate);
            subjectKeyIdentifierString = "Key-id";

            keyInfo.Id = $"KeyId-{subjectKeyIdentifierString}";

            // Create the SecurityTokenReference element with wsse prefix
            XmlElement securityTokenReferenceElement = soapEnvelope.CreateElement("wsse", "SecurityTokenReference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            // Create the KeyIdentifier element
            XmlElement keyIdentifierElement = soapEnvelope.CreateElement("wsse", "KeyIdentifier", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            keyIdentifierElement.InnerText = subjectKeyIdentifierString;

            // Add ValueType attribute to KeyIdentifier
            keyIdentifierElement.SetAttribute("ValueType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3");

            // Append KeyIdentifier to SecurityTokenReference
            securityTokenReferenceElement.AppendChild(keyIdentifierElement);

            // Create the Reference element
            XmlElement referenceElement = soapEnvelope.CreateElement("wsse", "Reference", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
            referenceElement.SetAttribute("ValueType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3");
            referenceElement.SetAttribute("URI", $"#KeyId-{subjectKeyIdentifierString}");

            // Append Reference to SecurityTokenReference
            securityTokenReferenceElement.AppendChild(referenceElement);
            // Add the wsu namespace declaration to the SecurityTokenReference element
            securityTokenReferenceElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:wsse", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            
            // Set the wsu:Id attribute to the securityTokenReferenceElement
            XmlAttribute wsuIdAttribute = soapEnvelope.CreateAttribute("wsu", "Id", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd");
            wsuIdAttribute.Value = $"STRId-{subjectKeyIdentifierString}";
            securityTokenReferenceElement.SetAttributeNode(wsuIdAttribute);
            
            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoNode(securityTokenReferenceElement));
            // Create the KeyInfoX509Data and add it as a child of the KeyInfo object

            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

            return keyInfo;
        }
```

Here is the Example XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ns="http://logius.nl/digipoort/koppelvlakservices/1.2/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566038">binarysecuritytoken</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="SIG-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566445">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa ns soapenv"/>
                    </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#TS-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280565037">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsse wsa ns soapenv"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>5bI1/rqLbK6vCD3cPBxkHCLfhbk=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566041">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ns"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>9X/ljiuWBBCvtlKMzYoxmoqiLAY=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566042">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ns soapenv"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>uxv6IREYRgNPdcmoX8IFhCff8cM=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566043">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ns soapenv"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>UDCeO2rcpBRezwcJBVTq/t/s96c=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566044">
                        <ds:Transforms>
                            <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                                <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="ns soapenv"/>
                            </ds:Transform>
                        </ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <ds:DigestValue>lbnkNYvWlwrkyRJuZ7anSJdclMM=</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>e8z0pi7IkzT84Tz73aQoE6PVuFd+ht7jr9daKkhLgKh+QU01swbOLAFM2OvEyp6DIjZKYSptP5x1 comzrFRnd+Sqp/IvF/fmh2JWYlVIgaW8oXcHMlDnzop2U/sQFKND71Fke3LovmCVQoJpK+IMlhTj +DDgU24UJf03SaT1tNcZCsFHAgBhgofwWCCy8c3iuF2NW4NgyI6xsJ6FOa+0JhIIv1IlGPBpF9z2 KsXb40uONG4EKAzOClNSfWr+1Tf0nSdz3D1xTuQlIkOi6C94vP58TS/DW1luH7MHJIJtEPLgMuZ6 EnkG8aBhz00i+KB5A2d8oFpplmcx33usbNCpgQ==</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566039">
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566040">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566038" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280565037">
                <wsu:Created>2017-12-27T13:53:25.650Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2017-12-31T01:13:25.650Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
        <wsa:Action xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566044">http://logius.nl/digipoort/wus/2.0/aanleverservice/1.2/AanleverService/aanleverenRequest</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566043">uuid:a923122a-3332-4711-b719-51204de8f267</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566042">https://cs-bedrijven.procesinfrastructuur.nl:443/cpl/aanleverservice/1.2</wsa:To>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="id-EBA33C7F5357EA682B151438280566041">
        <ns:aanleverRequest>
            <ns:berichtsoort>Jaarrekening</ns:berichtsoort>
            <ns:aanleverkenmerk>testjaarrekening</ns:aanleverkenmerk>
            <ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
                <ns:nummer>12345678</ns:nummer>
                <ns:type>KvK</ns:type>
            </ns:identiteitBelanghebbende>
            <ns:rolBelanghebbende>Bedrijf</ns:rolBelanghebbende>
            <ns:berichtInhoud>
                <ns:mimeType>application/xml</ns:mimeType>
                <ns:bestandsnaam>jaarrekening.xbrl</ns:bestandsnaam>
                <ns:inhoud>contentxbrl</ns:inhoud>
            </ns:berichtInhoud>
        </ns:aanleverRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: This posting is a continuation of a previous posting.  One issue was solved in previous posting.  Does XML pass online checkers?  You may have an issue with key padding see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66234/why-does-rsa-signature-need-padding.  To make it harder to hack encryption the encryption key can be padded with random characters.  Some library default to padding and other do not.  So padding option you are using may not match the padding used on server.

Comment: I think I solved the hashing. I signed an element that should not be signed compared with the fact that i used XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform. Now i am getting again the error: WssecurityException CWWSS6001E. Key object was not obtained. But key id is set. I also added as securitytokenreference. I will edit it in my post.

Comment: i think you mean Digest? it's all new for me. but i checked the documentation: Canonicalizatie http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#
Digest http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1
Signature: http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1

Comment: You are missing the tag c# in this posting that was in your previous posting.  You can validate xml in Visual Studio by using menu Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Than paste you xml into view.  Errors will show up as compiler errors in the view Error List.  I found two issues.  1) The xml posted above was missing the last two closing tags Header and Envelope.  I added these two tags.  There was no errors in the Error list but two lines were highlighted in green.  See my next comment

Comment: In error list change pulldown to Build + Intelisense.  There are 4 warnings.  I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm still researching.  New error seems to be from changes you made adding method : SignedXmlWithId signedXml = new SignedXmlWithId(soapEnvelope);

I found one possible issue.  The xml you posted has extra spaces in the namespaces at top of file where you have returns.  Make sure you put the namespace on one line instead of two.

The last namespace (wsu:Id="soap-id") I think is part of the issue.  Still researching.

Update : remove the namespace above and replace with

`xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"`

Then change following element

From : wsu:Id="timestamp-id" To : xsd:Id="timestamp-id"

See posting below :

['Malformed Reference Element' when adding a reference based on an Id attribute with SignedXml class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099156/malformed-reference-element-when-adding-a-reference-based-on-an-id-attribute-w)

Note sure.  I think the dates of the namespace may be old and ID using a base64 string is new. It may be "XML Signature 2.0"

See
https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core2/Overview-note-diff.html

Look at sample XML in para 2.1 for ID.  The namespace is version is 2000/09.  Then look at algorithm which is version 2010.

Warning 1

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureValue' element is invalid - The value 'Value' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureValueType' - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.    ConsoleApp10    C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp10\ConsoleApp10\XMLFile1.xml   87
```

Warning 2

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The 'Id' attribute is invalid - The value 'KeyId-daW0db2sMi2xKB4vf21Qij+gHzU=' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:ID' - The '+' character, hexadecimal value 0x2B, cannot be included in a name.    ConsoleApp10    C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp10\ConsoleApp10\XMLFile1.xml   88
```

Warning 3

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:X509Certificate' element is invalid - The value 'MyCertificate' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:base64Binary' - Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.   ConsoleApp10    C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp10\ConsoleApp10\XMLFile1.xml   104
```

Warning 4 : This warning can be ignored since you do not have a body

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The element 'Envelope' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Body' in namespace 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'.    ConsoleApp10    C:\Users\xxxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp10\ConsoleApp10\XMLFile1.xml   110
```

Comment: Many thanks for you research and sorry for my late response. I need the SignedXmlWithId class because it solves the error invalid references (i need this references because it is required by the receiver). If i change the time-id as you suggest i get that error again. I am not experienced, but i think it has todo with the wsu. I will share my SignedXmlWithID. By the way, i have a body in my xml. I changed the KeyID to a temporarily fixed description to avoid the '+' error. But still the same error. It was the only error i got when i paste my output in the XML-file in Visual Studio

Comment: I don't see the other errors by the way, perhaps i solved them already.

Comment: I believe the error is due to the version of namespace being too old.  Your hash method may be "XML Signature 2.0" and the older namespaces do not support the new signature.  You need to change the namespaces to a new version.  Most likely the SignedXmlWithId method.  Look at the XML that you code that is working and see if the namespaces are different from the namespaces from the code that did not work.  For example `<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">` It may be the following schema that was an issue wsu:Id="BST-Key-id"

Comment: i don't see it. i followed the namespaces from the documentation and checked it with the documentenation. and in my xml . i added also my AddKeyInfoPFX method.  my hashmethod is: sha1.

Comment: Are you saying that all the namespaces in your original xml and the namespaces in the one with  SignedXmlWithId  are the same?  The only differences in the two xml is the hash?  I'm just curious for future postings.

Comment: I think i don't understand what you mean. I checked the output XML and compared it with my code. i know that i've little experience in this stuff so sorry for my answers. my binary security token is generated:             var export = certificate.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, password);
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(export); is that correct or is that maybe the cause of the problem?

Comment: I said compare working and non working xml which are strings.  Is the only difference the hash?

Comment: I added the sample XML, i think that is what you mean with working XML? I compared it, i see some differences, especially <ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="wsa ns soapenv"/>. Do you think that is the problem?

Comment: Your xml is missing the 'ds' namespace so instead of using the ds namespace the soap is using the default namespace and giving error because the wrong namespace is being used.

Comment: First line i have: xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  That is the namespace definition (URL).  You also have to include the ds in the tags like the example.

Comment: I updated my new output XML above. I now get the response: RSA signature did not verify.

Comment: The following is giving an error `<ds:SignatureValue>{securitytoken}</ds:SignatureValue>`

Comment: Error says  Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureValue' element is invalid - The value '{securitytoken}' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:SignatureValueType' - The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. ConsoleApp10 C:\Users\joel\source\repos\ConsoleApp10\ConsoleApp10\XMLFile1.xml 52

Comment: i replaced my binary securitoken by {securitytoken} on this forum. it's a string of more than 2000 characters

Comment: Do not see update.  You can validate xml in Visual Studio by using menu Project : Add New Item : Xml File. Than paste you xml into view. Errors will show up as compiler errors in the view Error List.   See if signature is correct.

Comment: After The XML is as follows: i replaced that text. I validate in Visual Studio: No issues found.